# PHP Escape All Special Characters

Tags: php

I have a string that has to be passed as an argument in some operations. This string will very often contain special characters (non encoded; ie no `\n`, `\t`, etc).

What I would like to accomplish is to escape all of these special characters with a `\`. Below is my, very primitive, solution. I'm looking for a more streamlined version or possibly something built in to PHP to assist with this.

```
$array = str_split($string);
$escape_me = []; //special chars here
$i=0;
foreach($array as $char){
    if(in_array($char,$escape_me))
        $array[$i] = '\\'.$char;
    $i++;
}
$escaped = implode('',$array);
```

**EDIT**

This is for Bash and FTP commands.

I attempted `escapeshellarg()`. When I try to escape `$` it only returns `"$"` which I expected a `\` to be placed in front of the `$`

Comment: Depends on what characters https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php won't work?

Comment: What are you doing with this string that it needs to be escaped? The best method to use is entirely dependent on the use case. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: The first option did not work for me. I was optimistic about the second but it only accepts a string for the second argument. Would be great if it could accept an array. @AbraCadaver

Comment: @Sammitch, that being the case I suppose I would want to research what characters have special meanings for each of my cases and then populate my array with those characters

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel, upside down and backwards. Just tell us what your use case is. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Sammitch bash and ftp commands

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: Look closer. `escapeshellarg()` returns single-quoted strings in which `$` doesn't need to be escaped.